# XSL - Generating list of files from directory on network

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I am trying to list directory files with xsl using `collection` function. It seems to work for normal use case (searching in a local directory), but it fails when searching on a path on the network: eg. \\name_of_machine\the\path\to\folder

The log error is:

```
FODC0002: The file or directory
  file:/D:/the/current/location/of/the/executing/xsl/%5C%5Cname_of_machine2%5Cthe%5Cpath%5Cto%5Cfolder does not exist
```

And a snippet from my code:

```
<xsl:variable name="docList" select="for $f in collection($dir) return lower-case($f)"/>
```

So, basically, the `collection` function is prepending the current location of the XSL file that is executing the code and then it escapes all \ (backslash) characters.

How is it possible to use the collection function for retrieving files over network ?

EDIT:
I am using Saxon-HE 9.8.0-15

Comment: I think, a file URI to represent an UNC path on Windows for Java would be `file:////name_of_machine/the/path/to/folder` but I have no idea whether it then works with the `collection` directory search "magic" of Saxon 9.

Comment: I'm afraid there's a long history of problems with the representation of UNC file names as URIs. Firstly, there's a lack of standards: until fairly recently, the RFCs for the file: URI scheme were hopelessly vague. Related to this, there are different ways of doing it in different products: Java and .NET do it differently. But whatever else you do, the collection() function expects a URI, not a filename, and URIs do not contain backslashes.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for the info ! Which should be the best approach when accessing files on network with Saxon if backslashes are not allowed ?

Comment: In the end, I have used the solution @MartinHonnen suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use e.g. `<xsl:variable name="doc-list" select="uri-collection('file:////name_of_machine/the/path/to/folder?select=*.xml')"/>` to get a list of URIs to files in a directory with Saxon 9. I think the URI syntax to represent such a path is `file:////name_of_machine/the/path/to/folder`.

A test here on a Windows 10 machine using Saxon 9.8 gives

```
java -cp 'C:\Program Files\Saxonica\Saxon9.8HE\saxon9he.jar' net.sf.saxon.Query -t -qs:"uri-collection('file:////machine-name/Users/marti/SomeFolder/xml?select=*.xml')"
Saxon-HE 9.8.0.15J from Saxonica
Java version 1.8.0_252
Analyzing query from {uri-collection('file:////machine-name/Users/marti/SomeFolder/xml?select=*.xml')}
Analysis time: 194.6869 milliseconds
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>file:////machine-name/Users/marti/SomeFolder/xml/sample1.xml file:////machine-name/Us
ers/marti/SomeFolder/xml/sample2.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply ! I know that UNC syntax is as specified in the example from https://kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Knowledge/48745 and you can not access it other way. When I write the URL as stated, Saxon does not know what to do with it.

Comment: What does "as stated" refer to, my suggestion in the answer or the syntax from the article you linked to? And which error exactly do you get from Saxon?

Comment: I have tried multiple times with your example until I figured it out: it seems there was also a misleading behavior that made me believe that uri-collection did not return correctly, but after fixing it I can confirm that your solution works. Thanks a lot !

Comment: In other words: it works with uri-collection('file:////machine-name/Users/marti/SomeFolder/xml?select=*.xml')